# jQuery Toggle - Sticky on Bottom - Reverse

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a Toggle function like this exact like this one :

```
http://gyazo.com/26fc509c540e5175c07593b57caef386
```

But i have some troubles too make it reverse, So the contact box must be showed down instead up, exact like the gif file

This is what i have right now :

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpRVEa
```

Can somebody help me with it please? Thankyou

This is the HTML :

```
<div class="widget-style" id="widget"><a id="widget" hef="#"> Click here for more info</a></div>

<div class="contact-style" id ="contact" > Contact <hr>
  <p>More information in here</p>
<p>And More information in here</p>
<p>More information in here</p>
<p>And More information in here</p>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.widget-style {

  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding:14px;
  margin-left:40%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.contact-style {

  width: 400px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color:white;
  border:1px solid #000;
  color:black;
  font-size:18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding:14px;
  margin-left:37%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:48px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

p {
  font-size:14px;
}
```

And this is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#contact").hide();  

$( "#widget" ).click(function() {
  $( "#contact" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it: https://jsfiddle.net/qkk6a4tf/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="fullwidget">
    <div class="widget-style" id="widget"><a id="widget" hef="#"> Click here for more info</a>
    <span class="arrowup">&#8593;</span>
    <span class="arrowdown">&#8595;</span>

    </div>
    <div class="contact-style" id="contact">Contact
        <hr>
        <p>More information in here</p>
        <p>And More information in here</p>
        <p>More information in here</p>
        <p>And More information in here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.widget-style {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
}
.contact-style {
    width: 298px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#fullwidget {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -201px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
.widgetActive {
    margin-bottom: 250px;
}
```

**JS**

```
//&#8593; Up arrow
//&#8595; Down arrow
$(".arrowdown").hide();
$(".arrowup").show();
$("#widget").click(function () {
    $(".arrowup").toggle();
    $(".arrowdown").toggle();
    $("#fullwidget").toggleClass("widgetActive");
});
```

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Comment: i was trying to hide the space between them if they slide up with - > transition: 0.0s; , but that not work, can i let them stick? just like the example?

Comment: Very very sorry, included the wrong link, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qkk6a4tf/2/) one does work.

Answer (score 0):

would this work? I decided to use animate and click function;

Since i couldnt find any mistakes in your example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $d = $('.container');
  $('.button').click(function() {

    dont();

  });

  $('.container').mouseleave(function() {
    doo();
  });

  function doo() {
    $d.animate({
      bottom: '-75px'
    });
  }

  function dont() {
    $d.animate({
      bottom: '000'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  bottom: -75px;
}
.a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="button">click</div>
  <div class="a">asdasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes Exactly your way is also good, but i was trying to convert it into my design: `http://codepen.io/xcoder/pen/GJvKEN` , but i don't succeed can you fix it in my design? Thanks alot!